# How check response content in view test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to check if response objects contain label witch certain value.I have view which add value for certain label if conditions are fulfilled.Of course it works because I checked manually but I want to write test for this.

I tried to use assertContain and assertIn, but it doesn't work or I'm using this wrong:

```
class TaskIndexAPI(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='TestUser',
            password='test1234'
        )
        Task.objects.create(
            name='Task for test',
            creator=user,
            status='Unauthenticated',
            completion_date=date(2019, 4, 9),
            description='This is description for test purposes',
            warning_if_delayed=''
        )

    def test_check_if_delayed(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('tasks_index'), format='json')
        self.assertContains(response, 'This task is delayed')

    def test_check_if_delayed(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('tasks_index'), format='json')
        self.assertIn('This task is delayed', response)
```

This is fragment of view which add value for object label:

```
class UserTasksAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(creator=self.request.user)

    def check_if_tasks_are_delayed(self, queryset):
        checked_tasks = queryset
        for task in checked_tasks:
            if task.completion_date <= date.today() and status == 'Unfinished':
                task.warning_if_delayed = 'This task is delayed'
                task.save()
            else:
                task.warning_if_delayed = ''
                task.save()
            return checked_tasks

    def get(self, request):
        user_tasks = self.get_queryset()
        tasks = self.check_if_tasks_are_delayed(user_tasks)
        serializer = UserTasksSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I think you should check like: `self.assertIn('text', response.data)` or `response.json`?

Comment: With response.data is better than it was but still it's showing me that  'This task is delayed' isn't in response.data but I can see that it is:     self.assertIn(('warning_if_delayed', 'This task is delayed'), response.data)
AssertionError: ('warning_if_delayed', 'This task is delayed') not found in OrderedDict([('count', 1), ('next', None), (
'previous', None), ('results', [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('name', 'Task for test'), ('completion_date', '2019-04-19'), ('
status', 'Unfinished'), ('creator', 'TestUser'), ('warning_if_delayed', 'This task is delayed')])])])